# Why do I get an error "[Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence" when trying to install pillow using pip?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install pillow, but when I run `pip install pillow` in the cmd I get the following message:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/b6/8960697526a79bd1cb4520293078be3a10d725f23f20abbee298ebdeaabd/Pillow-6.2.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (1.9MB)
     |ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Python 3.8.2 is already installed on my computer and I added it to PATH.

I also ran `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and nothing has changed.

What is the problem? Do I need to update the Python version?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Have you tried `pip3 install pillow` or `python 3 -m pip install pillow`? (Side note: are you using a virtual environment? You _really_ should be. Don't pollute your global packages with `pip`-installed stuff.)

Comment: `pip` is for Python 2, `pip3` is for Python 3

Comment: Not necessarily, @ForceBru. It depends how everything is set up. But that's likely the issue.

Comment: @Chris, OP's `pip` is trying to download `Pillow-6.2.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` (for CPython 2.7 on 64-bit Windows), so, given that they claim they've installed Python 3, there should be `pip3`, or at least `python3`. But that's Windows, so it could also be `py`

Comment: I'm just saying it's not a simple as "`pip` is for Python 2, `pip3` is for Python 3". Other users may find this question later. We don't want to mislead them if we can help it.

Comment: Just download the Python .exe installer from https://python.org and run it — don't use `pip`.

Comment: @Chris is right. The assumption that `pip` is for Python 2 and `pip3` is for Python 3 doesn't always hold. One could have multiple versions of Python 3 on the same system for instance, in a Python 3 virtual environment `pip` points obviously to a Python 3 interpreter (the one in the virtual environment), etc. So it is best to entirely avoid instructions such as `pip3 install Something`.

Comment: I tried to run this command `pip3 install pillow` and got 
`Successfully installed pillow-7.1.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`
Why should I avoid this command? Do you know how to uninstall?

Comment: @ShirCohen What is it exactly that you are trying to do? You seem to have already installed Python 3.8.2, and now you want to install _Pilllow_ for _Python 3.8.2_, is that right? If yes then find out the exact path to the binary for the _Python 3.8.2_ interpreter and execute the following: `C:\path\to\python3.8.2\python.exe -m pip install Pillow`. Read my answer and the links in their entirety from top to bottom for more details.

Comment: Im trying to update python version. I downloaded Python 3.8.2, installed it in my computer and added it to PATH, but when I run `python --version` I get `Python 2.7.17`. I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you know how the `PATH` environment variable works? When you enter just `python`, meaning without any file path, then that `python` command is looked up in all the directories that are listed in `PATH`. The first match wins. So look at your `PATH` (for example call `echo %PATH%`) and then look in every single directory listed until you find one that has a `python.exe` (or `python.bat` or any other extension listed in `echo %PATHEXT%`).

Answer (score 2):

**Installation using third party PPA repository**

**Step 1:** First install the Ubuntu software properties package if it’s not already installed on your system.

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

**Step 2:** After that run the commands to add the PPA.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

**Step 3:** Finally, run below to install Python 3.8

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3.8
```

You can check as below:

```
$ python3 --version
```

> Python 3.8.1

OK done.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `pip`, `pip3`, etc. scripts ever. Instead always prefer the more explicit and surefire way of calling *pip*'s executable module for a specific instance of the Python interpreter, for example:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install Pillow
```

References:

- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/
- https://snarky.ca/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-on-how-to-install-packages-for-python/

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if Python3 is correctly installed by, for example, running `python3 -V` in the command-line (this will show you the installed version)

   - This should show something like `Python 3.8 ...`
   - If you get an error here, like it is an unknown command, something probably went wrong during the installation...
2. Run `pip3 install pillow` to install pillow (Python 3)

Answer (score -1):

Kindly download it at [Python official website](https://www.python.org/).

There is an option to update your version during the installation which is very useful.