# Updating from Python 3.5.2 to Python 3.8 using deadsnakes PPA is not working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I can't update Python on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from my Python 3.5.2 to 3.8. I found an existing post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61601747/) which shows how to update Python to 3.8. I tried those steps are follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
```

However, after the third step, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: try `apt-get search python | grep 3.8` ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: tim@LAPTOP-0FOJB2OC:~$ apt-get search python | grep 3.8
E: Invalid operation search
tim@LAPTOP-0FOJB2OC:~$

Comment: I presume you can't just upgrade to a more recent Ubuntu version where Python 3.8 is already the default?

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy Use `apt search` or `apt-cache search`.

Comment: also you can try build from source, such as https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/. just search for similiar tutorials according to you os version. you may need this option because sometimes os don't have latest prebuilt packages.

Comment: @LeiYang thanks. I am attempting a build from source. Will post once I complete.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My ubuntu did not have the latest pre-built packages so I had to install from source according to the following guide: [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.8.0.tgz
cd Python-3.8.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j 8
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Works great, thanks for the summary. Note that this **does not** overwrite the default system python3 binary, so you have to be explicit, eg: `python3.8 --version`. Also I ran into `AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'` when trying to create a new virtual environment with virtualenv, but [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/venv.html) worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The deadsnakes repo is no longer available for Ubuntu 16.04. You have to build python yourself. Please check my answer for [installing any python version using pyenv on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72227238/1195050).

Comment: after this procedure Ubuntu becomes a brick with broken shell, I had to edit .bashrc manually after loading the rescue copy from flash card

Comment: Ok noted. Probably your .bashrc did not end with a new line. I fixed it in the example. Thanks for the info @GeorgeHazan